# How do I delete a service with a custom action?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-services, custom-action, setup-deployment

Following what I found [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/816169), I was able to construct a Setup and Deploy project which properly installs the service with which I am working.
Unfortunately, there is absolutely zero information regarding how to UNINSTALL a service when I update the application (and likely, the service which comes with it).

How do I add an uninstaller to a service Project installer?

In the ProjectInstaller class I added the following bit of code:

```
[System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission( System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand )]
public override void Uninstall( IDictionary savedState ) {
    base.Uninstall( savedState );
    try { this.TRSInstaller.Uninstall( savedState ); } catch { }
}
```

I had to do it like that because trying it without the try/catch resulted in the service being properly removed, but there was an exception thrown that would not allow me to remove the entire program, so I couldn't install the new version either.

However, this does not remove the service.

This is the code for the ProjectInstaller class that VS spat out:

```
namespace TriviaRetriever {
    partial class ProjectInstaller {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary> 
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose( bool disposing ) {
            if ( disposing && ( components != null ) ) {
                components.Dispose( );
            }
            base.Dispose( disposing );
        }

        #region Component Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent( ) {
            this.TRProcessInstaller = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceProcessInstaller();
            this.TRSInstaller = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller();
            // 
            // TRProcessInstaller
            // 
            this.TRProcessInstaller.Account = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;
            this.TRProcessInstaller.Password = null;
            this.TRProcessInstaller.Username = null;
            // 
            // TRSInstaller
            // 
            this.TRSInstaller.Description = "Service for automatically downloading your trivia.";
            this.TRSInstaller.DisplayName = "Trivia Retriever";
            this.TRSInstaller.ServiceName = "TriviaRetriever";
            // 
            // ProjectInstaller
            // 
            this.Installers.AddRange(new System.Configuration.Install.Installer[] {
            this.TRProcessInstaller,
            this.TRSInstaller});

        }

        #endregion

        private System.ServiceProcess.ServiceProcessInstaller TRProcessInstaller;
        private System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller TRSInstaller;
    }
}

namespace TriviaRetriever {
    [RunInstaller( true )]
    public partial class ProjectInstaller : System.Configuration.Install.Installer {
        public ProjectInstaller( ) {
            InitializeComponent( );
        }

        [System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission( System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand )]
        public override void Uninstall( IDictionary savedState ) {
            base.Uninstall( savedState );
            try { this.TRSInstaller.Uninstall( savedState ); } catch { }
        }
    }
}
```

What do I need to do to this to make it successfully remove the windows service when I uninstall the application? (They are tightly bundled together; if one is not present, neither should be the other).

Answer (score 0):

That article does tell you how to do the uninstall -it's lurking in the phrase "Notice that Primary output appears under Install, Commit, Rollback and Uninstall. " which means that not only is there an install custom action there is an uninstall custom action. So if you've added all the custom action nodes it should be enough.

Also you don't need to call your uninstall from the existing uninstall because you are in an uninstall method for which base.Uninstall will uninstall the service. Note that the uninstall does not try to stop the service, so reboots may be required to completely uninstall the service.

Upgrading services with a RemovePreviousVersions upgrade is really difficult since they changed the upgrade behavior in VS 2008. This thread goes through the issues and solutions:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b2d1bd22-8499-454e-9cec-1e42c03e2557/how-to-deal-with-error-1001-the-specified-service-already-exists-when-install-a-service-using?forum=winformssetup

It's beter to get away from using code to install and uninstall services. It's completely unnecessary because Windows Installer and MSI files have built-in support for it (but VS setups don't). More info here, scroll down to Installing Services with Visual Studio:

http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msi/tips.htm